# Using PHP & MySQL to sort Events by multiple types.

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I need to create a small piece of code to allow me to filter my events database based on category types users have selected.

I currently have it working for users who have only one category selected...

```
  $user_qstring = "SELECT types FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
  $user_result = mysql_query($user_qstring);
  $user_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_result);

  $type_filter = $user_row['types'];
  if(isset($type_filter) && $type_filter !="") {
  $day_events = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_events WHERE day='".$day_id."' AND     
  type='".$type_filter."'";
  }else{
  $day_events = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_events WHERE day='".$day_id."'";
  }
```

I need to alter this code so that if $type_filter is set and contains multiple categories in the following format.

```
Festivals,Sports,Education
```

And have the query automatically add...

```
OR type='".$type_filter[2]."' OR type='".$type_filter[3]."' OR ect...
```

I have been able to solve the problem using multiple...

```
elseif(){
}
```

Statements, but need a solution that is scalable to unlimited types.

I know I need to start by changing $type_filter to a list using explode...

```
$type_filter = explode(",", $user_row['types']);
```

But I'm still having trouble putting it all together for a short elegant solution.

Comment: It looks like you are getting the filters from a query result, so checking for injection is probably not appropriate here. However, if the users can set the filter data at some other stage, you need to cleanse it when they input it. If you make them pick from a predefined list which they cannot edit, then it is probably safe PROVIDED YOU are careful when making the filter lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to confirm that $type_filter does not contain single quotes first otherwise you're an easy target for sql injection attacks.

```
$day_events = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_events WHERE day='".$day_id."' AND type IN ('" . implode("','", explode(',', $type_filter)) . "')";
```

Comment: or just run each array member through `mysql_real_escape_string().`

Comment: Thanks works great, I will have to search sql injection attacks. Doesn't sound good.

Comment: If I am reading his Q correctly, the data is from a query result, not from POST/GET

Answer (score 0):

try something like the follwing sql

```
select * from ... where type in ('one', 'two', ...) ...
```

and as a remark - *always* escape get/post data using mysql_real_escape_string or you are vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: If I am reading his Q correctly, the data is from a query result, not from POST/GET

Comment: could be, but better safe than sorry :)